# Trying to play something in OpenAL, but it never gets out of the AL_INITIAL state

Tags: c++, openal

I'm attempting to play an audio file using OpenAl, but it's not actually playing anything. When I check if the audio file is playing after calling alSourcePlay, the state is still AL_INITIAL.

Here's where I play the audio:

```
// Make sure the audio source ident is valid and usable
if ( audioID >= MAX_AUDIO_SOURCES || !mAudioSourceInUse[audioID])
    return false;

int sourceAudioState = 0;

if(!alIsSource(mAudioSources[audioID]) == AL_TRUE) return false;

alGetError();
// Are we currently playing the audio source?
alGetSourcei( mAudioSources[audioID], AL_SOURCE_STATE, &sourceAudioState );

if ( sourceAudioState == AL_PLAYING )
{
    printf("Currently playing!\n");
    if ( forceRestart )
        stopAudio( audioID );
    else
        return false; // Not forced, so we don't do anything
}
alSourcePlay( mAudioSources[ audioID ] );
if ( checkALError( "playAudio::alSourcePlay: ") )
    return false;
alGetSourcei( mAudioSources[audioID], AL_SOURCE_STATE, &sourceAudioState );
printState(sourceAudioState);
if(sourceAudioState == AL_PLAYING)
{
    printf("Now playing!\n\n");
}
return true;
```

mAudioSources is an array of buffers created by alGenBuffers. The file is loaded with

```
mAudioBuffers[bufferID] = alutCreateBufferFromFile(filename.c_str());
```

Which doesn't cause an error in alGetError. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`alutCreateBufferFromFile` will not cause an error in `alGetError`. You have to use `alutGetError` (note the prefix `alut` instead of `al`) instead. If `alutCreateBufferFromFile` fails, it will return `AL_NONE` which is a valid buffer: the `NULL` buffer which will not be played.

Check the [ALUT documentation](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/The%20OpenAL%20Utility%20Toolkit.htm) for information on `alutGetError` as well as the [OpenAL Specs](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL%201.1%20Specification.pdf).